# gsutil Insufficient permission trying to create and mount storage bucket

Tags: google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-platform, gsutil

I'm trying to create and mount a Google storage bucket on a Ubuntu Linux instance using `gsutil`.

```sh
sudo gsutil mb -c STANDARD -l us-central1-a gs://test-bucket
```

Here's what I'm getting:

> Creating gs://test-bucket/...
> AccessDeniedException: 403 Insufficient Permission

I've been searching around for a solution with no success. Can anyone help?

Comment: Are you a member of the project editors or owners group for the default project ID that you're using for gsutil?

Answer (score 0):

Check to see who is the account managing your VM instance from the GCloud Dashboard. Should be the compute service OR app account that is automatically created.

In the initial configuration settings you should see the Cloud API list that will state whether or not that user has Cloud Storage capability.

If not You will have to recreate your VM instance.

- Create a GCP snapshot of your VM
- Delete VM instance
- Create a new instance using it existing snapshot. (allows you to start where you left off in new VM)
- When creating the VM under API give the user full access which will allow them to write to the Cloud storage using the gsutil/gcsfuse commands.
- THEN permissions from the Cloud Storage will be a concern but your root user should be able to write.